# Why do I have a urine smell under vanity in bathroom

Tags: smell, vanity

I live in a condo & under my vanity it smells like urine which makes the whole bathroom smell like urine. Why & how to get rid of this!!  My cabinet is wood & I’ve clean with lysol but still smells. Toilet no smell just under my sink inside vanity. Please help

Comment: Do you have a pet?

Comment: I had a sink with a totally corroded  drain assembly. The old guy who lived there used a urinal bottle to keep from having to risk falling going to pee at night. Guess where that bottle got dumped every morning?  This caused a slow leak that accumulated in cabinet floor . Only option was replace cabinet and under it do a helluva clean up and then seal the floor . Maybe previous owner was doing the same at your condo. Or a cat litter box was kept in the cabinet  lol

Answer (score 1):

This may be a case of mold or mildew which can emit a urine like smell.

I lived in a lower level apartment for a time that was overly humid and this urine smell would crop up in enclosed areas or behind furniture from time to time.

In this case you need to ensure you improve ventilation/airflow in the affected areas, to stop the mold problem from getting worse.

Once you have better airflow, you can deal with the scent by putting vinegar in a spray bottle and lightly misting all the affected surfaces. Let the vinegar dry, then wipe down the surfaces with a rag and warm soapy water. If the smell persists, make a solution of baking soda dissolved in water and mist all the surfaces with that. Once again let it dry before wiping up. Be sure not to get it too wet, dampness is the enemy.  You can repeat the whole process a few times if the smell is particularly strong/persistent.

in my experience this process got rid of the odor, but if you haven't fixed the overall humidity issue the problem will keep coming back.

Also, if the cabinet is made of particle board and the problem is longstanding, the scent may have permeated the entire thing and be really hard to eliminate.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is a leaking toilet seal.  This allows sewage to seep into the subfloor and as the water evaporates the urine gets concentrated and smells.  (I know this from personal experience and it's nasty!)

I had to remove the toilet, tear up the vinyl floor covering, tear out the contaminated subfloor, and replace them all with a new toilet seal.  The floor joists were not affected so I didn't replace them.

It could also be a problem with the sink trap under the vanity but generally that smells like feces instead of urine.